# PHP Mysqli Obtaining top 5 results

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("mysql10.000webhost.com","a1982502_test","PASS","a1982502_test");
$query = "SELECT server,title FROM tickets ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Ok so that's what I have done so far, what I want it to do is to get the top 5, then I want to be able to sort them like
`$title`1 to 5
and
`$server`1 to 5.So I can display them in notifications

Would this fetch the $server1 fetch the first server in the row?

```html
$sql = "SELECT server,title FROM tickets ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $serverrow = $row['server'];
  $titlerow = $row['title'];
  
  $server1 = $serverrow[1];

    }
}
```

Comment: And what you were getting right now.

Comment: idk, im not sure when to start, if i could be pointed in the right direction to be able to throw them into variables i want it to be like this screen shot http://prntscr.com/7c5l2f with $title . $server

Comment: something like SELECT server,title FROM tickets where id IN (SELECT id FROM tickets ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER BY title ?

Comment: You need to post your table schema

Comment: this is what the table schema looks like http://prntscr.com/7c5ne6 or http://prntscr.com/7c5nhi

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not cear. I assume you're asking how to sort by multiple columns. Here is an example:

```
SELECT server, title FROM tickets ORDER BY time DESC, title ASC, server ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: i want the data the 5 rows to be put into variables for example SELECT server,title FROM tickets ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 5 to title1,title2,title3,title4,title5 and server1,server2,server3,server4,server5 so i can be able to have like a notifications that show recent things

Comment: There are dozens of examples in the web. You should use prepared statements. Take a look at PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: $sql = "SELECT server,title FROM tickets ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $serverrow = $row['server'];
  $titlerow = $row['title'];
  
  $server1 = $serverrow[1];

    }
}